# method not able to call from react dom

Tags: reactjs

**listItems** present in render(). all functionality is working fine.
i am  trying to click on the row then it will execute  **projectDetails()**. but it is showing below error:

[image]

**inside render()**

```
var listItems = this.state.projectList.map(function (item, index) {
                return <tr key={index} onClick={this.projectDetails(item, index)}>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.description}</td>
                    <td><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"  onClick={
                        function() {
                            showconfrim("Do you want to delete this Project?");
                        }
                    }></i></td>
                </tr>
            });
```

**method**

```
 projectDetails(item, index) {
        console.log(index);
    }
```

**constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            activePage: 1,
            projectList: []
        };

        this.projectDetails = this.projectDetails.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: use arrow function here: `this.state.projectList.map((item, index) => {` in map callback method. Another issue is here: `onClick={this.projectDetails(item, index)}`, it should be `onClick={e => this.projectDetails(item, index)}`.

Comment: thanks got the soultion

Comment: Use `bind` in map function to use the `this` context.

`function (item, index) {
                return <tr key={index} onClick={this.projectDetails(item, index)}>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.description}</td>
                    <td><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"  onClick={
                        function() {
                            showconfrim("Do you want to delete this Project?");
                        }
                    }.bind(this)`